# Как вставить html-код из одного файла в другой

Tags: html5

Хочу вынести шапку сайта с навигацией в отдельный файл, а потом пробовал через html-импорт ее вставлять в каждый документ из этого файла по гайду https://habr.com/ru/post/230751/
К тегу header присвоил id header и его указал в js, но ничего не происходит. Нашел что импорт уже не поддерживается. Дайте пожалуйста способ это сделать, в js вообще полный ноль, сайт локальный (на компьютере).

Comment: всегда можно использовать SSI (Server Side Includes — включения на стороне сервера), чтоб не учить современные технологии :) ну, или учить их https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924823/is-there-a-way-to-import-html-into-an-html-file